# set delegate for textfields on UITableViewcell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextfielddelegate

I use "tags" for identifying textfields inside a UITableView in my swift code. I need to implement UITextFieldDelegate functions like textfieldshouldreturn and textFieldShouldBeginEditing. But in most examples, these delegate functions shows textfields on UIView, but  not inside a UITableView. Where should I set the delegate for the textfields and how can be? (I know that for a static textfield under a UIView, we set delegate under the functions like ViewDidiLoad or similar life cycle methods.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the controller that has your table view as IBOutlet or Property should conform to UITextFieldDelegate, and set the textfield's delegate to self in table view's dataSource method cellForRowAt indexPath

```
yourCell.yourTextField.delegate = self

yourCell.yourTextField.tag = indexPath.row
```

Comment: I am not using a name for the textfield, using tag.

Comment: "yourCell.yourTextField.tag" here I assume yourTextField is the name of the textfield,but I have not given any name to the textfield.

Comment: it's the name you gave to the UITextField outlet in your reusable UITableViewCell

Comment: Ok, I hae not yet given a name because I take values using tag code
eg:  if let txtField1 = self.view.viewWithTag(101) as? UITextField {
            name = txtField1.text!
        }

Comment: sorry I ignored a single warning in swift 3.0
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
has to change to
 func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
Now it works with tag and your code also. thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128684/discussion-between-sameh-salama-and-vinod).